# Unity warnings related to duplicatication of items

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I was working on Unity game project and after installing the firebase SDK ,I am coming accross these multiple warnings.Did anybody face them before and had luck resolving them?

[image]

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that Firebase is trying to create *menu items* that *already exist* in Unity.

One possible cause is that Firebase, without your knowledge already existed in your Unity project prior to your install attempt due to:

1. your project may be a modified Firebase tutorial
2. you created your project from scratch but you imported some 3rd party asset that included a copy of Firebase

So when you proceeded to import Firebase proper into a different folder (**External Dependency Manager**) it tried to create menu items that already existed.

Try to locate the other Firebase and either **delete** it or **upgrade** it.  Either way you only want **one**.